# R debug() "could not find function" even though it exists

Tags: r, function, debugging, scope

When I try to debug a certain function (itself defined within the function NbCluster), I get a `could not find function` error. I have checked and the function in question is definitely loaded when `debug` is called.

```
> data("USArrests")
> arrests <- scale(USArrests)
> source("NbCluster_copy.R")
> NbCluster_copy(data = arrests, diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 12,
+                   method = "ward.D2", index = "gap", alphaBeale = 0.1)
[1] "Indice.Gap exists"
Error in debug(fun = "Indice.Gap") : could not find function "Indice.Gap"
```

And the issue does not happen if I manually step through the function (by selecting and running lines instead of calling the function).
I tried making a minimal example, but was unable to, so I don't think it is the nested functions that are the problem.

```
###This works as expected, when I run "wrapper", debug is called from within the function:
wrapper <- function(x){
wrapper <- function(x){
  fun1 <- function(x){
    fun0 <- function(x){
      y = x + 1
      return(y)
    }
    debug(fun0)
    y = fun0(x) * 2
    return(y)
  }
  fun1(x)
}

> wrapper(2)
debugging in: fun0(x)
debug at #3: {
    y = x + 1
    return(y)
}
Browse[2]> 
debug at #4: y = x + 1
Browse[2]> 
debug at #5: return(y)
Browse[2]> 
exiting from: fun0(x)
[1] 6
```

This is the part  I added into the NbClust function.

```
        if(exists("Indice.Gap")){
          print("Indice.Gap exists")
        }
        debug(fun = "Indice.Gap")
```

right before the first call of `Indice.Gap`:

```
        resultSGAP <- Indice.Gap(x = jeu, clall = clall, 
                                 reference.distribution = "unif", B = 10, method = "ward.D2", 
                                 d = NULL, centrotypes = "centroids")
```

I only made very minor changes besides the one shown above, but if you want to look at the whole function, my copy is here: https://pastebin.com/wxKKDbHy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the quotes in debug and it should work:

```
debug(Indice.Gap)
```

should do the trick.

```
outer_fun <- function() {
   inner_fun <- function() 1
   ## does not work
   # debug("inner_fun") 

   ## works
   debug(inner_fun)
   inner_fun()
}

outer_fun()
```

Funny enough on the top level you can provide the function name as string:

```
debug("outer_fun") # works
debug(outer_fun)   # works
```

Comment: Agree. This is due to the function not existing in Global Environment. If Indice.Gap() exists in Global Environment, the code that the OP has should work.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! I never would have thought of that. And yeah the function I am trying to access is several levels deep.